# When i convert my video url to blob url in next js application then it says not a valid url, Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, blob, video.js

I am creating a video player using video.js. Everything works fine until i use the video url but when i use the blob url then it shows that not a valid url. I have given both jsx code first which have video url working fine but other is showing error that not valid url.

Player jsx with video url-

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

export const VideoJS = (props) => {
  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const { onReady} = props;
  let options = {
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    muted:true,
    sources: [{
      src: "http://localhost:3000/assets/videos/Video.mp4",
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }]
  };
  const handleContextMenu = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {

    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode. 
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add('vjs-theme-city');
      videoElement.setAttribute("controlsList","nodownload")
      videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log('player is ready');
        onReady && onReady(player);
      });

    // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
    // on prop change, for example:
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src(options.sources);
    }
  }, [options, videoRef]);

  // Dispose the Video.js player when the functional component unmounts
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(boburl);
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}>
      <div className='w-5/12' ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoJS;
```

Player with blob url-

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

export const VideoJS = (props) => {
  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const { onReady} = props;
  let boburl;
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/assets/videos/Video.mp4")
  .then(res=>res.blob())
  .then(blob =>{
    boburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    console.log(boburl)
  })
  let options = {
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    muted:true,
    sources: [{
      src: boburl,
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }]
  };
  const handleContextMenu = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {

    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode. 
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add('vjs-theme-city');
      videoElement.setAttribute("controlsList","nodownload")
      videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log('player is ready');
        onReady && onReady(player);
      });

    // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
    // on prop change, for example:
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src(options.sources);
    }
  }, [options, videoRef]);

  // Dispose the Video.js player when the functional component unmounts
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(boburl);
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}>
      <div className='w-5/12' ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoJS;
```

Folder structure-

```
|-video-player
  |-styles
    |-global.css        
  |-pages
    |-api
      |-hello.js
    |-index.js
    |-VideoJS.js
  |-public
    |-assets
      |-videos
        |-video.mp4
    |-favicon.ico
```

Please guide me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

To help you resolve the issue with the blob URL not being recognized as a valid URL in your video player using video.js, you can try the following solutions:

1. Set the `blob` as the video source directly:

   const videoSource = URL.createObjectURL(blobObject);

   const player = videojs('my-video', {
   sources: [{
   src: videoSource,
   type: 'video/mp4'
   }]
   });
2. Use the `addRemoteTextTrack` function with the blob URL:

const videoPlayer = videojs('my-video');

videoPlayer.addRemoteTextTrack({
kind: 'captions',
src: URL.createObjectURL(blobObject),
label: 'English',
srclang: 'en',
default: true
});

```
3. If the above solutions don't work, you can try converting the blob URL to a data URL before using it in video.js:

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  const dataURL = reader.result;

  const player = videojs('my-video', {
    sources: [{
      src: dataURL,
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }]
  });
};

reader.readAsDataURL(blobObject);

Make sure to replace `'my-video'` with the ID or class of your video element in the examples above.

These solutions should help you resolve the issue with the blob URL not being recognized as a valid URL in video.js.`enter code here`
```

Comment: This answer has a high probability of being produced by an AI. AI content is **strictly** not allowed on Stack Overflow and **will not be tolerated**. Read the guidelines on AI content here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy